# Populating rails form with AJAX using checkbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I am having a hard time integrating an AJAX call to populate my form. I do not know if I formatted this correctly and what I should be using to fill in my jSON data on the form. Any help is much appreciated.

The end goal is to be able to click a checkbox to populate the address in a form for a new contact. I want to be able to populate the address with the same address as the customer they belong to.

I have looked at examples where AJAX is used to populate the shipping form address to be the same as the billing form address however that does not work for me because I do not have both address forms on the page.

This is part of view page for the new contact:

```
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2'>
      <p>Address Same as Customer <input id="same_customer_address" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="1" /></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= address.label :line1, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= address.text_field :line1,class: "form-control", id: 'line1'%>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= address.label :line2, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= address.text_field :line2,class: "form-control", id: 'line2'%>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= address.label :city, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= address.text_field :city,class: "form-control", id: 'city' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= address.label :state, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= address.text_field :state,class: "form-control", id: 'state' %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <%= address.label :zip, class: "col-sm-2 control-label", id: 'zip' %>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <%= address.text_field :zip,class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <% end %>
```

---

```
Customer
has_many :contacts
belongs_to :address

Contact
belongs_to :address
belongs_to :customer
```

---

```
Contacts Controller
  def new
    authorize Contact
    @contact = @customer.contacts.new
    @contact.build_address
    phone_types = ['Cell','Work','Home']
    3.times { @contact.phones.build(phone_type: phone_types.shift) }
    @contact_types = @@contact_types
    # authorize @customer
  end

  def same_as_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @customer }
    end
  end
  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_contact
    @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
  end
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :email_sec, :title, :contact_type,
     address_attributes: [ :line1, :line2, :city, :state, :zip, :id ],
     phones_attributes: [ :phone_type, :number, :id ])
  end
end
```

---

```
$('#same_customer_address').click(function() {
var customer_address;
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "/contacts/same_as_customer",
  datatype: "json",
  data: { line1: line1,
          line2: line2,
          city: city,
          state: state,
          zip: zip },
  success: function(data){
    customer_address = data;
  }
});
if ($("#same_customer_address").is(':checked')) {
  console.log("customer address is filled");
  $('#line1').val("customer_address.line1").val();
  $('#line2').val("customer_address.line2").val();
  $('#city').val("customer_address.city").val();
  $('#state').val("customer_address.state").val();
  $('#zip').val("customer_address.zip").val();
  } else{
    console.log("field is empty");
    $('#line1').val("");
    $('#line2').val("");
    $('#city').val("");
    $('#state').val("");
    $('#zip').val("");
  };
});
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Right now I am getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in console. I do not believe I have my ajax call correct or the form to receive the data back correct.

Comment: Is a contact something like an order in your application?

Comment: Contact is the person who works for the customer. Like the business and their employees. This is for a task application.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works...

```
 $('#same_customer_address').change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    var customer_address;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "/contacts/same_as_customer",
      datatype: "json",
      success: function(data){
        customer_address = data;
        console.log("customer address is filled");
        $('#line1').val("customer_address.line1");
        $('#line2').val("customer_address.line2");
        $('#city').val("customer_address.city");
        $('#state').val("customer_address.state");
        $('#zip').val("customer_address.zip");
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("field is empty");
    $('#line1').val("");
    $('#line2').val("");
    $('#city').val("");
    $('#state').val("");
    $('#zip').val("");
  };
});

# Contact Controller

  def same_as_customer
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @customer.address }
    end
  end
```

## Alternative Approach

Might I suggest an alternative approach... Instead of populating the form, pass the params of that checkbox as true and duplicate the address in your controller and then save the record.

Comment: This did not work I am still getting: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded. Do I need to alter my form to accept the data back? Would I be able to do your alternative approach if I have more items in my form other then the address?

Comment: I think we are getting somewhere now we are getting a missing template contacts/same_as_customer. We want this to render on contacts/new page.

Answer (score 0):

Use classes instead of ids:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2'>
        <p>Address Same as Customer <input id="same_customer_address" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="1" /></p>
    </div>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :address do |address| %>
    <div class="address-fields">
        <div class="form-group">
            <%= address.label :line1, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= address.text_field :line1, class: "form-control line1" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= address.label :line2, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= address.text_field :line2, class: "form-control line2"%>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= address.label :city, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= address.text_field :city, class: "form-control city" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= address.label :state, class: "col-sm-2 control-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= address.text_field :state, class: "form-control state" %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <%= address.label :zip, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"%>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= address.text_field :zip, class: "form-control zip" %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Now lets use the classes to copy the JSON values to the inputs:

```
var $form = $('#my_form_id');

$form.on('copy_address', function(){
  $.getJSON("/contacts/same_as_customer").done(function(data){
    var attributes = ['line1', 'line2', 'city', 'state', 'zip'];
    $.each(attributes, function(i, attr){
      $fields.find('.form-control .' + attr).val(data[attr]);
    });
  });
});

$form.find('#same_customer_address').one('change', function(){
   if (this.checked) {
     $form.trigger('copy_address');
   }
});
```

Comment: However the rest of your approach is still kind of broken - the URL does not take an `id` param. And the action does not seem to return JSON containing an address. I would recommend you take a step back from your current code and just think it though.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up populating the record in the backend. It does not populate the form like I originally wanted but it does what I needed it to do which is to update the address record.

Contact Controller:

```
def create
    puts params.inspect
    authorize Contact

    @contact = @customer.contacts.new(contact_params)

    same_as_customer

    @contact.update({user_id: current_user.id}.tap do |h|
                h[:address] =  @address if @address
            end
        )

    if @contact.save
        params[:contact][:emails].each do |email|
        @contact.emails.create(email:email)
      end

        redirect_to customer_account_url(@customer), notice: 'Contact created!'
    else
        @contact_types = @@contact_types
        @contact.errors.full_messages
        render :new
        # render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def same_as_customer
    if params[:customers][:address] == '1'
         puts "checkbox is checked"
        @address = Address.create!(@customer.address.as_json.except('id'))
    else
         puts "checkbox is unchecked"
    end
  end
```

New Contact View:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-2'>
      <p>Address Same as Customer <input id="same_customer_address" name="customers[address]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```